# Google Tag Manager for iframe

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Does anyone know how to deploy Google Tag Manager succesfully in an Iframe?
I am working on the JavaScript widget for external partners which will be embedded on their websites as an iframe.

I want to track some of the events in my widget with Google Tag Manager which sends collected data to Google Analytics.  I went through the whole configuration and set up some of the first triggers and events.  For testing purposes, I put my iframe with the source code to my widget on one of the clients' websites. When I use a Google Tag manager for debugging my tags I can see all of my tags being fired and working correctly as they should from that iframe. Unfortunately, when testing it on the website without the debugger, none of the events appear in Google Analytics. Since I am the creator of the widget and I have full control over my source code what could be the reason for those events not being registered to Google Analytics but still being fired in the debugger? I went through the documentation of Google Tag Manager, and it says clearly that I can track my iframe if I have the access to the source code to configure it.

Any help and insight will be very appreciated here, did anyone faced a similar problem, and what could be the possible solution?

Comment: Could you give us more details on your Google Tag Manager configuration?